# General position for pair of subvarieties belonging to the same Hilbert scheme component

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $Z\subset X$ be smooth projective $\mathbb C$-varieties (irreducible) such that the component $\mathcal Hilb_Z(X)$ of the Hilbert scheme containing $[Z]$ is smooth at $[Z']\in \mathcal Hilb_Z(X)$ as soon as $Z'$ is smooth (and positive dimensional).
Is it easy to find an example of such a situation where, moreover for general pairs $([Z'],[Z''])\in \mathcal Hilb_Z(X)^2$, $Z'\cap Z''$ are not dimensionally transverse (i.e. $dim(Z'\cap Z'')>max\{2dim(Z)-dim(X),0\}$)?

Comment: Without the irreducibility assumption, there is a simple example: Let $X$ be $\mathbb P^2$ and blow up two points $P_1$, $P_2$ producing exceptional divisors $E_1,E_2$. Let $Z$ be the union of $E_2$ with the strict transform of a general line through $P_1$. Then $X$ and $Z$ are smooth projective and $Z$ has negative intersection with $E_2$, so every divisor in the same Hilbert scheme component has negative intersection with $E_2$ and thus contains $E_2$. So the intersections of two such divisors is not transverse. And Hilbert schemes of divisors on varieties with no Picard group are smooth.

Comment: With irreducibility, any example must have $Z$ with codimension at least $2$, hence $X$ with dimension at least $3$.